# Is there a mistake in the proof of Theorem 4 in Kaplansky's Commutative Rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Here is a theorem (Theorem 4) in Kaplansky's *Commutative Rings*.

> Let $R$ be an integral domain. Let $S$ be the set of all elements in $R$ expressible as a product of principal primes. Then $S$ is a saturated multiplicatively closed set.

The definition of a saturated multiplicatively closed set is as follows:

> A multiplicatively closed set $S$ is *saturated* if $x\in S$ implies that $S$ contains all the divisors of $x$.

When the author was proving the theorem, he said that

> To prove that $S$ is saturated we assume $ab\in S$ and have to prove that $a$ and $b$ lie in $S$.

**My Question:** 
I am wondering if $a=p$ is a prime and $b=1$, then $ab=p\cdot 1\in S$ implies that $a=p\in S$ and $b=1\in S$. But $1$ should not be in $S$. Maybe I misunderstand something or how to fix the problem.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why should 1 not be in $S$?  In fact, some authors *require* that 1 be in every multiplicative set, but even if this book does not, certainly no one disallows it.

Comment: @Ted I think $1$ is not a product of primes.

Comment: It's an empty product, of zero primes.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3140411/eulers-totient-phi-function-as-a-product-of-primes) is a question related to empty product